# splitting a dot delimited string into words but with a special case

Tags: python, regex, parsing, split

Not sure if there is an easy way to split the following string:

```
'school.department.classes[cost=15.00].name'
```

Into this:

```
['school', 'department', 'classes[cost=15.00]', 'name']
```

Note: I want to keep `'classes[cost=15.00]'` intact.

Comment: This is one example, but it is not very specific. What are the conditions for not splitting? Is it always inside `[]` or could it by inside `{}` or `()` or `""` etc.? Or are the rules even more complicated?

Comment: Is `[cost=15.00]` really a qualifier of `classes` or of `school.department.classes`?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I made this up, but it's a qualifier for classes. I've been working on my own JSON path for simple queries. The ones I found online for python does not not filter by attribute (e.g. python-jsonpath-rw ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'school.department.classes[cost=15.00].name'
>>> re.split(r'\.(?!\d)', text)
['school', 'department', 'classes[cost=15.00]', 'name']
```

More specific version:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([^.\[]+(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)(?:\.|$)', text)
['school', 'department', 'classes[cost=15.00]', 'name']
```

Verbose:

```
>>> re.findall(r'''(                      # main group
                    [^  .  \[    ]+       # 1 or more of anything except . or [
                    (?:                   # (non-capture) opitional [x=y,...]
                       \[                 # start [
                       [^   \]   ]+       # 1 or more of any non ]
                       \]                 # end ]
                    )?                    # this group [x=y,...] is optional
                   )                      # end main group
                   (?:\.|$)               # find a dot or the end of string
                ''', text, flags=re.VERBOSE)
['school', 'department', 'classes[cost=15.00]', 'name']
```

Comment: This may fail if the string contains something like `classes[cost=foo.bar]`.

Comment: I agree with Ashwini. The solution seems too specific.

Comment: I think the answer is as good as the question. What do you intend to suppress the splitting? The brackets? The '=' symbol?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary true, I've created one that supports `[...]` separately

Answer (score 2):

Skip dots within brackets:

```
import re
s='school.department.classes[cost=15.00].name'
print re.split(r'[.](?![^][]*\])', s)
```

Output:

```
['school', 'department', 'classes[cost=15.00]', 'name']
```

Comment: I originally had this but then what if your variable name is `department2`

Answer (score 1):

This could get messy in a hurry, you may need to actually parse this string instead of just splitting it up:

```
from pyparsing import (Forward,Suppress,Word,alphas,quotedString,
                        alphanums,Regex,oneOf,Group,delimitedList)


# define some basic punctuation, numerics, operators
LBRACK,RBRACK = map(Suppress, '[]')
ident = Word(alphas+'_',alphanums+'_')
real = Regex(r'[+-]?\d+\.\d*').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))
integer = Regex(r'[+-]?\d+').setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
compOper = oneOf('= != < > <= >=')

# a full reference may be composed of full references, i.e., a recursive
# grammar - forward declare a full reference
fullRef = Forward()

# a value in a filtering expression could be a full ref or numeric literal
value = fullRef | real | integer | quotedString
filterExpr = Group(value + compOper + value)

# a single dotted ref could be one with a bracketed filter expression
# (which we would want to keep together in a group) or just a plain identifier
ref = Group(ident + LBRACK + filterExpr + RBRACK) | ident

# now insert the definition of a fullRef, using '<<' instead of '='
fullRef << delimitedList(ref, '.')

# try it out
s = 'school.department.classes[cost=15.00].name'
print fullRef.parseString(s)
s = 'school[size > 10000].department[school.type="TECHNICAL"].classes[cost=15.00].name'
print fullRef.parseString(s)
```

Prints:

```
['school', 'department', ['classes', ['cost', '=', 15.0]], 'name']
[['school', ['size', '>', 10000]], ['department', ['school', 'type', '=', '"TECHNICAL"']], ['classes', ['cost', '=', 15.0]], 'name']
```

(It isn't difficult to put "classes[cost=15.00]" back together if you need to.)

Comment: Very cool. I might consider this if I need more robust parser.

Answer (score 0):

#The simplest method to split the sentence is by using .split('.') as shown below:

```py
s = 'school.department.classes[cost=15.00].name'

s.split('.')
```

This is your expected output:

```
['school', 'department', 'classes[cost=15', '00]', 'name']
```